# Android Room database RxJava flatmap chain requests

Tags: android, rx-java, android-room, flatmap

I am trying to get a pair of:

```
Pair<User,List<Messages>>
```

I read this article: [RxJava patterns](https://medium.com/devnibbles/rxjava-the-first-3-patterns-4c112a85b689)

I basically try to get the the user first. Then once I have the user, I want to get all the messages of that user:

```
mDisposable.add(
                userViewModel.getUser(id)
                .flatMap(user -> messagesViewModel.getFromUser(user.getId()),(user, messages) -> new Pair<>(user, messages)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(//update view based on user and messages);
```

The code doesn't work, it complains about the params passed to flatmap.

- `userViewModel.getUser(id)` returns a `Single<User>`
- `messagesViewModel.getFromUser(user.getId())` returns a `Single<List<Message>>`

The rx documentation and method definition for flatmap is very confusing. How can I achieve this? Or is there another way to accomplish this?

Interestingly enough it seems to work with Observable:

```
mDisposable.add(
                Observable.just(1)
                .flatMap(item -> Observable.just(2), Pair::new)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to documentation, `Observable` has [`flatMap()`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#flatMap-io.reactivex.functions.Function-io.reactivex.functions.BiFunction-) function with signature like

```
public final <U,R> Observable<R> flatMap(Function<? super T,? extends ObservableSource<? extends U>> mapper,
    BiFunction<? super T,? super U,? extends R> resultSelector)
```

it's exactly what you use in the latest case. But `Single` only has [`flatMap()`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Single.html#flatMap-io.reactivex.functions.Function-) with signature like

```
public final <R> Single<R> flatMap(Function<? super T,? extends SingleSource<? extends R>> mapper)
```

that's why you can't directly use it as you wish. If you still want to use `Single` and solve the problem, you can use next expression

```
userViewModel.getUser(id)
    .flatMap(user -> messagesViewModel.getFromUser(user.getId())
                             .map(messages -> new Pair<>(user, messages)))
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
```

Comment: Thanks. Yeah I checked that there is no such method signature with a BiFunction for Single. I guess using map inside flatMap is the only way to go with Single.